# pushbot and phonegap build integration

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, pushbots

I am trying to integrate pushbot with phonegap build android app.
 reference :  https://pushbots.com/developer/docs/phonegap-sdk-integration

As on their guid i have downloaded blank project from githud
link: https://github.com/pushbots/blank-cordova-app/

I replaced app id with pushbot ad id and sender id with google app id.
The app has build and installed successfully. The problem is that still the dashboard device number stays 0. I couldn't push messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my mistake. I have palced project id intead of project number